# On click event not working as a delegated event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add an on click event to an <a> element inside a  <li>. 
When the page is loaded the event is added fine but when I add it dynamically another <a> (pressing a button) it isn't working.
 I read that the problem is because the event is handled and not delegated. 
What do I have to change in my function to get the event delegated?

Also I need that the added <a> has the class "deleteAttachment". 


Here is the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 var a = 0;
            $('button[data-button="attachment"]').on("click",function () {
                var ul = $(this).next("ul");
                var li = ul.find("li:last-child");
                var element ="<li name='li3'>";
                    element += '<a class="deleteAttachment">' + a + '</a></li>';
                li.before(element);                
                a++;
            });


            $('li').on("click", 'a.deleteAttachment', function () {
                alert("click");
            });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div>

        <button name="Button1" data-button="attachment">
          button1
        </button>
        <ul name="ulbuton1">            
            <li name="li3"> 
               <a class="deleteAttachment">a</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <button name="Button2" data-button="attachment">
          button2
        </button>
        <ul name="ulbuton2">            
            <li name="li3">
                <a class="deleteAttachment">b</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <button name="Button3" data-button="attachment">
          button3
        </button>
        <ul name="ulbuton3">            
            <li name="li3">
                <a class="deleteAttachment">c</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding the LI as well, so delegating to that won't work, you have to delegate to something that is actually there, like the UL

```
$('ul').on("click", 'li a.deleteAttachment', function () {
      alert("click");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Event delegation means that you add the event handler to a parent rather than to its children so that, irrespective of the number of children that need to handle a certain kind of event, you will have only one handler (at the parent) for that event.

Actually, the event keeps on bubbling up until it finds a handler that catches it eventually. So you can place it anywhere "above" your element (in principle).

In your case, you are attaching the event to the `li`, which is supposed to be a child in this case.

You need to attach the event to its parent, which should exist already, so that when the event is triggered on the `li`, it is bubbled up to the parent, caught and executed.

Attach it to the `ul`, `div` or the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good solution to your question:

```js
$( "body" ).delegate( "a.deleteAttachment", "click", function() {
  //do your stuff here
});
```